# Parse two log files with timestamps with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, logging

I have two csv for a log with this shape:

log.csv: id,user_id,timestamp,event,model

and

log_attr.csv: id,name,value

an example of tables could be:

log.csv: id,user_id,timestamp,event,model

```
1,1,2021-11-19 22:25:21,start_model,A
2,1,2021-11-19 22:25:32,click_bar,A
3,1,2021-11-19 22:25:34,click_bar,A
4,1,2021-11-19 22:26:59,div_start_displaying,A
5,1,2021-11-19 22:26:59,div_end_displaying,A
```

and for log_attr.csv: id,name,value

```
1,viewUsed,desktop
2,barId,193284
2,keyword,host
3,barId,121384
3,keyword,Location
4,divId,15486
5,divId,15882
```

I need to do some statistics work, so I put all in two pandas tables.
What is the best approach for calculate things like: the time a certain div was shown and so the mean time for a certain user for the divs, or how many seconds or keywords a certain user clicked?
Is there any pandas method that can help me or I need to read each line and write some code for each event? For instance, how to create a table with the seconds calculated with the timestamp[i] - timestamp[i-1]?
maybe create a new table log_with_attr could help?
with this shape:
id,user_id,timestamp,event,model,[name1],[name2] (where name1, name2 are values in log_attr.name and the value will be value)
thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Creating a table with seconds calculated between 2 consecutive events**

Column Time Diff contains the time difference between itself and the previous event in your log file.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('log.csv', index_col='id')
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df['Time Diff'] = 0

df2 = pd.read_csv('log_attr.csv', index_col='id')

for i,row in df.iterrows():
    if (i > 1):
      tdiff = df['timestamp'].loc[i] - df['timestamp'].loc[i-1]
      df['Time Diff'][i] = tdiff

print(df)
```

You get the output as

```
    user_id           timestamp                 event model        Time Diff
id                                                                          
1         1 2021-11-19 22:25:21           start_model     A                0
2         1 2021-11-19 22:25:32             click_bar     A  0 days 00:00:11
3         1 2021-11-19 22:25:34             click_bar     A  0 days 00:00:02
4         1 2021-11-19 22:26:59  div_start_displaying     A  0 days 00:01:25
5         1 2021-11-19 22:26:59    div_end_displaying     A  0 days 00:00:00
```

**Calculate number of keywords clicked by a given user**

```
# merges log.csv and log_attr.csv in a single table
df3 = df.join(df2)
print(df3)
```

with output as:

```
    user_id           timestamp                 event model        Time Diff      name     value
id                                                                                              
1         1 2021-11-19 22:25:21           start_model     A                0  viewUsed   desktop
2         1 2021-11-19 22:25:32             click_bar     A  0 days 00:00:11     barId    193284
2         1 2021-11-19 22:25:32             click_bar     A  0 days 00:00:11   keyword      host
3         1 2021-11-19 22:25:34             click_bar     A  0 days 00:00:02     barId    121384
3         1 2021-11-19 22:25:34             click_bar     A  0 days 00:00:02   keyword  Location
4         1 2021-11-19 22:26:59  div_start_displaying     A  0 days 00:01:25     divId     15486
5         1 2021-11-19 22:26:59    div_end_displaying     A  0 days 00:00:00     divId     15882
```

Now use group by on the merged table to get number of clicks per keyword or other metrics per user.

```
# selecting keyword parameter rows
dfkw = df3[df3['name'] == 'keyword']
# group by user_id and keyword
kwc = dfkw.groupby(['user_id','value']).size()
```